# AMD RAID controller sees drives & RAID 1; Windows & RAIDXpert don't

Tags: windows-7, ssd, raid, sata

I've got two SSDs I'm trying to work in RAID 1 on a Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD5.

Here is the weird combination of all the different variables with a fairly ideal testing scenario (plenty of spare parts)...

- The AMD RAID controller (six SATA ports, not the Marvell controllers) sub-bios sees the drives, the bios sees the drives; all of this in either RAID or AHCI mode.
- The only way Windows 7 64 bit sees the drives is if they the controller is in AHCI mode; even if I had previously setup the drives in RAID 1 in RAID mode and rebooted with the controller in AHCI it still saw the drives separately. I've obviously went in to Computer Management/Disk Management and the only drives listed are the boot SSD and optical drives, absolutely nothing else.
- AMD's RAIDXpert utility does not see the drives at all.
- When I plug the drives in to a USB/SATA the drives are recognized just fine in my desktop and laptop.
- I have spare SSDs, cables, etc and have cross-tested SATA ports/SATA cables/SSDs. I need to eventually have three separate RAID 1s so using ports 0/1 for the first RAID is important.
- My boot SSD is on a completely separate Marvel controller.

I love building computers but I have *never* gotten *any* motherboard RAID controller to actually work *ever* hence why I've been stuck using two dedicated RAID controllers for my three RAID 1 setup. Am I missing something or is RAID support on motherboards a wild myth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Crucial MX550 / 512GB SSDs are incompatible with the AMD 990FX chipset / AMD SATA RAID controller. I returned them and will research what high performance SSDs *will* work with the controller. The rep at Crucial was honest and said they had no time frame on a firmware update.